# jQuery prevent submit form doenst work with if statement

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I got a problem

If i try to prevent a form submit by using this code

```
$(function(){
            $('#registerform').submit(function(e) {

                var benreg = $("#benreg").val()
                var pas1reg = $("#pas1reg").val()
                var pas2reg = $("#pas2reg").val();
                var submit = true;

                if(benreg === "" || pas1reg === "" || pas2reg === ""){
                    var submit = false;
                }

                if(submit === false){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

            });  
        });
```

... then it works, but when I use to show an info dropdown alert, it doenst work. I don't know why. My Form submit the data although the boxes are empty.

```
$(function(){
            $('#registerform').submit(function(e) {

                var benreg = $("#benreg").val()
                var pas1reg = $("#pas1reg").val()
                var pas2reg = $("#pas2reg").val();
                var submit = true;

                if(benreg === "" || pas1reg === "" || pas2reg === ""){
                    var submit = false;
                    var rel = new $.peekABar({
                        html: "Error message<br />" + '<img src="img/success.png"/>'
                    });

                    rel.show(); 


                }

                if(submit === false){
                    e.preventDefault();
                }

            });  
        });
```

What I have to do to get this working?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Have you considered putting your `peekABar` alert in the same `if` statement as `e.preventDefault()`?  I have a feeling that that might fix the issue.

Comment: don't redeclare `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
            $('#registerform').submit(function(e) {

                var benreg = $("#benreg").val()
                var pas1reg = $("#pas1reg").val()
                var pas2reg = $("#pas2reg").val();
                var submit = true;

                if(benreg === "" || pas1reg === "" || pas2reg === ""){
                    var submit = false;
                    var rel = new $.peekABar({
                        html: "Error message<br />" + '<img src="img/success.png"/>'
                    });

                    rel.show(); 

                    return submit;

                }

            });  
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, thats my solution. 
I noticed, that I includes the peekabar.js before I include the jquery.js. So if if call the peek a bar, my script causes an error and submittet anyway. 
Thnak you guys. :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
$(function(){
        $('#registerform').submit(function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();

            var benreg = $("#benreg").val()
            var pas1reg = $("#pas1reg").val()
            var pas2reg = $("#pas2reg").val();
            var submit = true;

            if(benreg === "" || pas1reg === "" || pas2reg === ""){
                var submit = false;
                var rel = new $.peekABar({
                    html: "Error message<br />" + '<img src="img/success.png"/>'
                });

                rel.show(); 


            }

        });  
    });
```

Just remove the e.preventDefault() in if else, move it after submit(function(e)){

Try the code.

Comment: Yes, this works for me. Thanks! But my form doesnt submit even if all textboxes are filled with data....

Comment: Form will never submit.